# Where are all the javax jars?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar

**Edit**: several fellow SOers have recommended just going to Maven repos, which of course have nothing to do with using Maven as part of one's build. I understand this. The point of this question is simple: **what websites, owned and maintained by Oracle, can I go to, to grab all my `javax` jars?** Not Maven repos. Not any other 3rd party repos. Oracle repos.

Let's say I don't like Maven, and don't want to have to go to a Maven repo to find my jars. How do I get `javax.injection`? How about `javax.validation`? Or any of the other `javax` jars?

They don't seem to be available via Oracle's Java EE downloads website (which is *shocking*). So I ask: what does one have to do to get the official, Oracle-blessed `javax` jars without having to consult a Maven repo?

Bonus points to anyone who can explain to me why these JARs seem to be intentionally difficult to find.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use maven you can download them from maven central manually via your browser : http://search.maven.org/

Comment: Again, a Maven reference. **Why do Oracle jars only seem to be available via Maven repos?!?!** Thats the point of my question. Shouldn't Oracle make them available somewhere, off an *Oracle* website?!?!

Comment: grepcode can help : http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh! Every single link on that page.... is a link to a *Maven* repo! Am I not speaking English here?!? Oracle owns Java. Why can't I find Java jars on an Oracle site? **This is like only being able to buy Suzuki cars at Nissan dealerships.**

Comment: No, this is like being able to buy pizza at the supermarket, and not at the pizza factory. Oracle and Maven are not competitors like Suzuki and Nissan. If Oracle don't want to bother hosting their jar and want to go with an intermediary it's their problem.

Comment: So is that the answer? Oracle doesn't host their own JARs? Are you answering my question, or being sarcastic here?! I refuse to believe that Oracle doesn't host their own JARs somewhere...

Comment: Maven has become the *de facto standard* for distribution and dependency management in Java. Aside from that ... download the JavaEE distribution from Oracle and they are *included*.

Comment: The JavaEE distro is just a shell script that does all sorts of voo doo when it runs, and then magically installs JEE on your system. But the jars are not included with the distro itself.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys: You are absolutely right that this is no way to run a railway. Nonetheless, it how it is run! Are you familiar with the classic "Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract" problem? Some of the jars that are distributed for JEE don't even contain valid class files.

Comment: There is actually a deeper point here, though. The output of the standards process is a standard - a document for human consumption. That standard may well describe and prescribe a set of classes. However, the classes themselves *are not an output of the standards process*. Anyone can come along and write an implementation of those classes which complies with the standard and hold them up as such. Hence, *there is no single definitive implementation of the classes*, but rather a marketplace of equally valid implementations.

Comment: Excellent points here @TomAnderson - I know I'm coming off as abrasive here, but I love Java, and the deeper I get into it, the more I feel like I have to defend it. And now, finding out that this is the way Java EE works is very disconcerting to me. And that "Absent code" item you mentioned, which I was not aware of, is downright **terrifying**.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys: I don't find you abrasive, but perhaps only because i often react this way too. I am much more scathing about defects in things i respect than, those i don't. When i come across some brain damage in Ruby, for instance, i just shrug and continue.

Comment: I would also like to see a culture where specs that produce definitions of classes also produce canonical implementations of those classes. Not reference implementations, but simply class files for the API elements themselves. To do this, specs would have to rigorously separate interface and implementation - for example, the existence of `HttpServletRequest` makes it impossible to do this for the servlet spec. Jars of those classes could then be provided alongside the specs from the JCP site (as they are for some specs, to be fair). Sadly, this requires a shift in how specs are done in Java.

Comment: There should be a additional bonus for people not using java. I'm so fed up with getting jar files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *javax* jars are owned and maintained by the [JCP projects](http://www.jcp.org/en/home/index) they belong to, since they represent Java standards. So, strictly they are not Oracle blessed but JCP blessed. So the JCP page is also the official place to look.

<del>For example if you navigate to the [JDO2 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=243) and click on the download page for the FINAL release. Under "Reference Implementation and Technology Compatibility Kit:" is a bullet which states: "The API jar is available from..." which links to the Jar containing the 'javax' API interfaces.</del>

Update:

> The API jar is available from http://db.apache.org/jdo/downloads.html under Apache 2.0 license.

If you follow the link it will tell you that for the jar:

**It can be downloaded from maven, or it can be built manually from the source code.**

Comment: **Thank you** @JasperSiepkes +1 - someone who finally understands why this is so confusing to me. I would happily give you the green check, however I still have one concern. As I have already pointed out, the `javax.validation` JCP site does not seem to contain the compiled API binaries. So it leaves me feeling uncertain as to whether or not JCP is always going to be a sure way to find the API libs. Any thoughts there? And thanks again!

Comment: The JCP jars are always derived from the standards document (otherwise they wouldn't be compliant with their own standard :-). The standards documents are ALWAYS on the JCP page. If an TCK exists (a piece of software to test if your implementation is compatible with the standard) it is also on the JCP page. The jar is a bit of a an ugly stephchild which nobody really cares about since its usually shipped with the implementation (and in theory easily created from the spec since its just a bunch of interfaces). To my knowledge there is no sure way of getting those jars (maven is your best bet).

Answer (score -1):

Here ya go:

- [javax.validation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303)
- [javax.inject](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)

Comment: Unfortunately those pages don't contain any links to the compiled binaries. They only contain links to the javadocs and PDF specs. Again, at a loss as to how *nobody* seems to know where to grab compiled binaries for Oracle jars, off an Oracle website.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys - both of those link to the reference implementations which have binary jars.

Comment: [This](http://people.redhat.com/~ebernard/validation/fab/hibernate-validator-4.0.1.GA.zip) is the reference implementation for bean validation? An HTML page that has the Red Hat symbol on it? Doubtful.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys - heh, didn't follow that one, the inject one has binaries.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys - not sure why you are interested in the APIs.  the whole point is that they come with the jee container.

Comment: And again, these are implementations of the `javax.*` APIs (Hibernate, etc.). I want the `javax.*` API libs themselves.

Comment: So where do the JEE containers get the APIs from?

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys - did you follow the links http://code.google.com/p/atinject/downloads/list ?

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys - the jee containers most likely get the jars from the maven repository, like everyone else in the world.

Comment: So... the JCP creates a new JSR. The JSR gets coded and approved, and then all the source code is handed off to the Maven central repo admins, who then compile the JARs and host it (exclusively) off their site? Why am I the only person who finds that to be **lunacy**?!?

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys - apparently.

Comment: And another point @jtahlborn....if I go to Maven Central right now and search for "javax validation".... you know what I get?? Version "1.1.0.Beta4". I don't want a darn beta version, I want a stable version. Apparently I can't get that on Maven, and according to you, anywhere else in the world. And that is craziness, even if I am the only person who thinks it.

Answer (score -1):

If you download Tomcat you can grab the servlet-api.jar from the lib folder.

Comment: No you can't it's not included in the core package you have to download 
the "full documentation" tar here https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi